# Create a trigger just update other all records in same table except new record

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have already asked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542383/unknown-system-variable-media-sortorder but no one answered it,
Please suggest a trigger code how to update other all records in same table except new record.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the same table on which the trigger is invoked. Triggers that update the same underlying tables do not execute in parallel. Please go through this 
[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).